# How can a dependent cmake target run all dependency targets first, and then fail if a dependency failed?

Tags: makefile, cmake, build

I have a *CMake* `coverage` target which collates a number of other component-specific coverage targets:

```
add_custom_target(coverage)

foreach(COMPONENT IN LISTS ALL_MY_COMPONENTS)
   ...
   add_dependencies(coverage
      ${COMPONENT}_coverage)
endforeach()
```

If one of the `${COMPONENT}_coverage` targets fails, then the `coverage` target fails immediately, but I want it to keep going and only fail after all the component targets have run, if one or more has failed. How do I do this?

I have tried, instead of the `add_dependencies` line, this:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET coverage
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${COMPONENT}_coverage)
```

...but this gives this just runs `cmake` and not `make`, and I cannot find a command to run the native generator. Replacing `${CMAKE_COMMAND}` with `make`, which is fine on Linux, still suffers from the main problem that if the component coverage target fails, then the catch-all coverage target also fails immediately.

Comment: As far as I know, neither CMake nor Make has no sematic of "deferred fail": once COMMAND returns non-zero, the whole build process is terminated. Instead of failing a sub-COMMAND, you could make it to write something into the file. Inside your custom target you could check that file and deduce a verdict. "I cannot find a command to run the native generator" - Variable [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) contains path to the generator.

Comment: To build a certain target via cmake regardless of the generator you use you can `cmake --build path/to/binary/dir --target target_name [--config Release]` (the `--config Release` part is only for multi config generators, which "unix makefiles" is not).

Comment: Btw: one approach that could work would be to use a cmake scripts to execute the targets and make it after the execution of all tasks is done; the script could look something like this: `set(TASK_FAILED False) foreach(TARGET IN ITEMS part1 part2) execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ... --target ${TARGET} WORKING_DIRECTORY ... RESULT_VARIABLE PART_RESULT) if (PART_RESULT) set(TASK_FAILED True) endforeach() if (TASK_FAILED) message(FATAL_ERROR "at least one part failed") endif()` (cmake scripts are run with the `-P` command line option)

Answer (score 3):

In general, this depends on which generator you're using, but since you say you're running `make` on Linux, I'm assuming you're running GNU Make.

Just pass the `-k` (for **k**eep going) flag to `make`. From the man page:

> Continue as much as possible after an error. While the target that failed, and those that depend on it, cannot be remade, the other dependencies of these targets can be processed all the same.

So that's either of these commands:

```
$ (cd build && make -k)
$ cmake --build build -- -k
```

Keep using `add_dependencies`, as you were. No need for the `add_custom_target`.